# Why does ImageView get smaller by increasing margin top size?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, margin, android-relativelayout

I have got a relative Layout in which I want to display one `Imageview` and one `TextView` with `background-image`.

If I didn't use any `margin-top` it works how I should, but if I increase the top margin of the ImageView the Image gets smaller.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout                                                                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerNameEnd"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/casino2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Player"
        android:textColor="@color/cream"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/roulette_EndPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/casino" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using `ConstraintLayout` if you are not benefiting from it? Since your `ImageView` s width and height are `wrap_content` and your root layout is not a `ScrollView`, it tries to put everything to the screen and when you add margin the image gets smaller. 

Note that the `ImageView` might have a padding around it

Comment: What do you expect to see instead? If you add top margin, then there's less space for the image to draw, right?

Comment: Remove the constraint layout part ,start with Relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use         `android:paddingTop="40dp"`

instead of marginTop

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is the same problem